# TrafficStats of a youtube player in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing an application which needs to gather information about the bytes transmitted and received of an embedded youtube player view.

I have tried to get the UID of the application and use the class TrafficStats to get these statistics. But I can see while the player is buffering that the number of bytes received and transmitted doesn't change. I think that the player has another UID but I can't find this one.
I have read also that some media player use the UID 1013 for mediaservers but also when I check the value of the traffic for this UID it doesn't change.

Could anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Before 4.3, TrafficStats were available from /proc/uid_stat//, since 4.3, it uses the stats are available at /proc/self/net/xt_qtaguid/stats. The new mechanism (4.3+), typically includes the media_server process bytes that were downloaded on behalf of that file. So depending on your OS version, you should decide whether or not to add the data used by media_server process (1013).

But this may be modifiable by using the function TrafficStats.setThreadStatsUid() More details here https://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/kernel-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

use

```
TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(android.os.Process.getUidForName("media"));
```

It worked well for android version below 4.4(kitkat).
I'm trying to find the way to get traffic in 4.4 and I haven't know the solution yet.